# SQL Server 2008 Query Between Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We are migrating database structures, so I have one database with the old structure and one database with the new structure (both on the same server). I want to write queries to copy data from one to the other. I am expecting to go table-by-table as the schema is different. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide more details to get a more specific answer, but in general you just use the three-part name:

```
INSERT INTO NewDB.dbo.TableName
SELECT <columns>
FROM OldDB.dbo.Tablename
```

Are you looking for a way to do this automatically for all the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can write cross database queries like so

```
INSERT INTO NewDatabase.Schema.Table
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM OldDatabase.Schema.Table
```

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use Import data under tasks.Right Click the Target DB -> Tasks ->Import Data .You can also specify the source-> target mapping here.. and also write queries